# beautifulsoupによるfind_allの利用方法について

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

スクレイピングにおいて値が" 3月調査 "であるspanタグを取得し，そのdata-value1属性値を取得したいと考えています。find_all関数を用いて以下のコードを実行しました。

実行コード

```
soup.find_all('span', text=" 3月調査 ")
```

取得したいhtmlタグ

```
<span data-key="tstat" data-key1="tclass1" data-key2="tclass2" data-matter="2" data-value="000001014549" data-value1="000001162554" data-value2="000001164846">
                                3月調査
                     <span class="stat-pc">[57件]</span>
</span>
```

結果は[]でした。どうすればタグ内の値が"3月調査"であるspanタグを取得できるでしょうか？

Comment: `list(soup.span.strings)` で文字列表示するとスペースの数とか, 後ろにスペース入らないとか分かりますよ

Comment: `data-value1`属性値を取得したいなら, (テキストをもとに探すのではなく)`data-value1`属性を持ってる要素を探すのがよいのでは？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。記載していないのですが，webサイトに”３月調査”のタグだけでなく，”4月調査”，”5月調査”などのタグも存在しており，属性値で区別するのが難しいと判断し，タグ内の値で区別しようと思いました。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

タグ内の値に"3月調査"を含むspanタグを取得したい場合は`find_all`でタグを取得してから[`get_text()`](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#get-text)で対象を絞る方法があります。

**サンプルコード**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

html = """
<html>
<body>
<span data-key="tstat" data-key1="tclass1" data-key2="tclass2" data-matter="2" data-value="000001014549" data-value1="000001162554" data-value2="000001164846">
                                3月調査
                     <span class="stat-pc">[57件]</span>
</span>
</body>
</html>
"""
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
spans = [t for t in soup.find_all('span') if '3月調査' in t.get_text()]

for t in spans:
    print(t.get_text(strip=True))
```

なおご質問のコードではspanが入れ子になっているため、`get_text()`関数でテキストを取得すると`3月調査[57件]`のように入れ子のspanタグの中身も返ります。
そのためサンプルコードの`if '3月調査' in t.get_text()`を`if t.get_text(strip=True) == '3月調査'`に書き換えるとヒットしなくなります。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。実際に試してみたのですが，自分の欲しいspanタグを取得することができました。もう少し絞り込む段階を分けて考えるのが必要だとわかりました。初歩的な質問でしたが返答ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<span data-key="tstat" data-key1="tclass1" data-key2="tclass2" data-matter="2" data-value="000001014549" data-value1="000001162554" data-value2="000001164846">
                                3月調査
                     <span class="stat-pc">[57件]</span>
</span>
<span data-key="tstat" data-key1="tclass1" data-key2="tclass2" data-matter="3" data-value="000001014550" data-value1="000001162555" data-value2="000001164847">
                                4月調査
                     <span class="stat-pc">[15件]</span>
</span>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
element = soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("3月調査")')
print(element['data-value1'])

#
# 000001162554
```

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。実際に試してみたのですが欲しかった値を取得することができました。CSSセレクターを使う方法もあったんですね。初歩的な質問に丁寧に答えてくださりありがとうございました。

Answer (score 0):

`data-value1`属性について, の回答。
ループの外側で調べる場合, マイナス記号含むので `attrs=` 引数与えるとよいかも
ループの内側で調べる場合は, コメントアウトしてるのを外すとよい

```py
for span in soup.find_all('span', attrs={'data-value1': True}):
    #if not span.has_attr('data-value1'):
    #    continue
    if '3月調査' in span.text:
        print(f'element: {span}')
        print(f'text: {span.text.strip()}')
        val = span['data-value1']
        print(val)
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。指定の属性値があるかないかでspanタグを絞り込む方法は思いつきませんでした。丁寧な回答ありがとうございました。